# Solve $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^2}{2n^3 + k^3}$ using Riemann sums.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

I am familiar with the definition of Riemann sums and how they are used to evaluate definite integrals. But I am completely stuck with this expression. I can't seem to extract any patterns that relate to Riemann sums (other than the limit and summation term). Am I supposed to assume an interval in terms of $k$ and try to formulate an expression of the form $f(x_i^*)\Delta x$? Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a question

I was thinking how to solve your sum using Cauchy's first theorem on limits, which says, if $\lim a_n=l$ then $\lim \frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots +a_n} n=l$.

Now in your case, let $a_k=\frac{(k/n)^2}{2+(k/n)^3}$, then $\lim a_n=\lim \frac 1 3=\frac 1 3$, thus By the theorem, $\lim \frac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k} n$ should be $\frac 1 3$.Therefore by this theorem, sum should be $\frac 1 3$

But as, Michael has done integration shows that the sum is $\frac 1 3 \ln(3/2)$.

What is going on here?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Cauchy's first theorem, but since this is a question adapted from a Calculus I course I don't think that would be required. Perhaps someone with more experience could offer some insight.

Comment: @PNDas: Cauchy theorem does  not apply because each term in sum depends on $k, n$ both and not just on $n$. So you can not think of each term like a term in a sequence. In General any term of a Riemann sum can not be viewed in this manner. Rather try to view the entire Riemann sum as a function of $n$ ie as a sequence.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you for your comment , but I have asked this in the following question.: 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3882947/cauchys-first-theorem-on-limits-and-integration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{2n^3+k^3}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(k/n)^2}{2+(k/n)^3}.$$

Answer (score 2):

It's $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}{2+\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^3}\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow\int_0^1\frac{x^2}{2+x^3}dx=\frac{1}{3}\ln|2+x^3||_0^1=\ln\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{2}}.$$