# Cauchy's first theorem on limits and integration

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, definite-integrals, solution-verification

This question is inspired from [original](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3882870/solve-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-1n-frack22n3-k3-using-riemann-s).

[iobtl](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/817404/iobtl) wanted to solve $$S=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k^2}{2n^3+k^3}$$ using Riemann integration.

$(1)$ I was thinking how to solve it using Cauchy's first theorem on limits, which says, if $\lim a_n=l$ then $\lim \displaystyle\frac{a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots +a_n} n=l$.

Now, let $a_k=\displaystyle\frac{(k/n)^2}{2+(k/n)^3}$, then $a_n=\frac 1 3\implies \lim a_n=\frac 1 3$, thus by the theorem, $\displaystyle\lim \displaystyle\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n a_k} n$ should be $\frac 1 3$.Therefore by this theorem, $S=\frac 1 3$

$(2)$ But as Michael did, integration shows $S=\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{2+x^3} \mathrm{d}x=\frac 1 3 \ln(3/2)$.

$(3)$ What is going on here?

I know integration is correct, then I am doing something wrong in the 1st part.

---

**EDIT:** In my book there is a problem to find the limit $$\lim \left[\frac 1{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac 1{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots+\frac 1{\sqrt{n^2+n}}\right]$$,
which the author solved in the following way,

Let $a_k=\frac n{\sqrt{n^2+k}}$ then $\lim a_n=\lim\displaystyle\frac 1{\sqrt{1+1/n}}=1$

Therefore by the theorem required limit is $1$.

---

That is why I found $S$ in this way.

Comment: In what you call Cauchy's theorem (and I would rather call it Cesaro's theorem !), the sequence $a_k$ **must not** depend on $n$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Cesaro's theorem (according to my book) is if $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$ then $\lim \frac {a_1 b_n+a_2 b_{n-1}+\cdots +a_n b_1}{n}= ab$,

Comment: What you wrote as $a_k$ is actually dependent on $k$ and $n$ so it is actually $a_{k,n}$. 

What you need to calculate is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n(\sum_{k=1}^na_{k,n})$ but what you have calculated is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n(\sum_{k=1}^na_{k,k})$.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri , Thank you, it makes sense now.

Comment: Apply your Cesaro with $b_n = 1$, you will get your Cauchy :)

Comment: What book is it ?